# Agora.io broadcast speaker video/audio to another channel(s)

Tags: react-native, agora.io

We are developing the following scenario and can only get the speakers audio to be streamed for some reason. Can someone give advice on how to implement this or if its even possible with Agora React Native SDK:

I just wanted to check that what we are doing is possible in Agora. So to clarify we have:

Channel 1: speaker 1, maybe speaker 2 - They will chat each other like normal

Channel 2: Audience 1, Audience 2 - They video chat to each other as normal + speaker 1 and speaker 2 video from Channel 1 (video and Audio but can't communicate with Channel 2 audience)

Channel 3+: same as Channel 2 but with different audience members.

Basically the speakers can be seen and heard by audience, but they cannot hear the audience. At the moment we have this working but the speakers video doesn't show to the audience, just the sound.

cheers
Mike

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is possible using multi channel features of the SDK. The only limitation with multi channel is that you can only publish your local video to one channel at a time, you can however subscribe to multiple videos (from multiple channels).